# Can I plot D3 graph from get request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, d3.js

I had a doubt that can I plot a graph from a get requests .The response is in json format.
My back-end is in nodejs and express

Comment: You absolutely can. Please post a sample of the JSON and what kind of D3 chart you're trying to make.

Comment: @chrispytoes I am trying to make multiple  charts as in d3 , for  temperature,pressure,etc. keys in a single page .Please help me with the solutions,how can I get started.The sample json res is`0: {temperature: "43C", humidity: "44%", pressure: "1 bar", rain: "65mm", wind: "65km/hr"}
1: {temperature: "28C", humidity: "29%", pressure: "1 bar", rain: "70mm", wind: "70km/hr"}
2: {temperature: "91C", humidity: "92%", pressure: "1 bar", rain: "61mm", wind: "61km/hr"}
3: {temperature: "56C", humidity: "57%", pressure: "1 bar", rain: "85mm", wind: "85km/hr"}`

Comment: Alright, well the fact that the data came from a get request is irrelevant. Is your question just about how to use D3 then? If so, there's plenty of resources to get started if you just google around. I'm not the best person to answer a question about D3 in particular.

Comment: @chrispytoes _well the fact that the data came from a get request is irrelevant_.Please explain what is irrelevant!